# Jquery; Find out when child window is finished loading

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC and Jquery.  I have an image link that the user clicks.  It opens something up some things in a new window.

```
Html.ImageLink("createreport",
               "Report",
               "GetPDFReport",
               "?sid=10",
               Url.Content("~/Content/images/pdf.png"),
               "Get Report",
               null,
               "imagelink",
               new { target = "_blank" },
               true,
               "reportRetrieved();"
               )
```

This opens up a new window for the user.  The reportRetrieved function gets called as soon as the link is clicked.  I have some clean up work that needs to be done after the new window gets fully loaded.

I could do it in the reportRetrieved function, but I have no way to tell if the child window has fully loaded or not.  Depending on the situation, the child window could take 2 seconds to load or 5 minutes.

So is there a way to put something in my reportRetrieved function that will wait for the child Window to finish loading and then run some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either manually open the window and attach a ready event to the resulting window's document:

```
$(window.open("your image url here").document).ready(handler);
```

or

Use your existing ImageLink, but point it to an HTML page with the image instead of just the image itself. The page can have it's own ready handler and calls back using window.opener:

```
$(document).ready(function () { window.opener.YourMethodHere() })
```